# Bash script to show git username in terminal

Tags: bash, git, gist

Does anyone know how to show `git username` in the terminal?

I am using the following bash script for the branch, but, since I have several accounts I would like to show as well `username` or `user email`

BTW, I know I can use `git config --global --list`. The idea is to see the info in the terminal without having to check every time, as with the `branch`

```
parse_git_branch() {
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}

export PS1="\u@\h \W\[\033[32m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

Comment: Note that typically, interactive shell configuration (as opposed to script development) is more welcome at our sister site [unix.se].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `git config --get` to get a single configuration value, like the username. Then, you can wrap it in a function:

```sh
parse_git_user() {
    git config --get user.email
}
```

And then you can incorporate it into the prompt (`PS1`) in any format you wish. E.g.:

```sh
export PS1="\u@\h \W\[\033[32m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] ($(parse_git_user))$ "
# Here -----------------------------------------------------------^
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you want to make sure you get the correct `user.email` for each of your projects?  @Mureinik eloquently answered the question, but I think this may help you or someone else searching.

Rather than have the `user.name` in your prompt, I suggest you set it based on the remote url.  That way it should just work™.
It works by using a zsh hook every time you change into a directory.

```
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook
set-git-email() {
  if [ -d .git ]; then
    remote=`git remote -v | awk '/\(push\)$/ {print $2}'`
    if [[ $remote == git@git.server.com:* ]]; then
       git config user.email user@email.com
    fi   
  fi
}
add-zsh-hook chpwd set-git-email
set-git-email
```